# binutils-2.20 install failed

Tags: linux, binutils

I am trying to install binutils in my mac.

`configure` works:

```
sudo ./configure --target=i386-elf --disable-nls --disable-werror
```

but the `make` command gives me a fatal error:

```
i386-dis.c:6671:21: fatal error: bracket nesting level exceeded maximum of 256
    { PREFIX_TABLE (PREFIX_VEX_3832) },
```

Any idea can help me out?

Comment: Probably you need a newer/different compiler with higher bracket nesting level limits.

Comment: You might want to ask your question over at the "SuperUser" sister page. You will more likely get good answers over there considering the topic of your question. You can find the link at the bottom of this page, in the footer.

Comment: You shouldn't *ever* run any step of compilation with `sudo` except for `make install`.